# Sending lots of data through POST or GET

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

I am trying to send an XML file from a textfield in my html, via ajax to a PHP file. This is the almighty PHP file:

```
<?php 
    $data = urldecode($_POST["xml"]);

    echo $data;
?>
```

Data is sent to this file as such:

```
$("#btn_save").click(function() {
    var data = escape($("#textfield").text());
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        url:        "validate.php",
        method:     "POST",
        data:       "xml=" + data,
        complete:   function(e) { alert(e.responseText); }
    });
});
```

Now, as long as I don't sent more than a few lines of code, it works as it should. When I paste in a 60 line XML file however, validate.php returns

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /xml_stylist/form/validate.php
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at dahwan.info Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is a lot of data? Most servers have a maximum allowed data input that is accepted.

Comment: *Always* check your Apache `error_log` before doing a search with Google, or even posting a question here. What does your error_log say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
method: "POST"
```

to

```
type: "POST"
```

that may do the trick.

Comment: ya beat me to it! I always that "type" _should_ be "method"...it would make sense

Answer (score 4):

BenSho is correct, the argument is called `type`. In addition:

```
$("#textfield").text()
```

I'm guessing that's a `<textarea>`. You shouldn't use `text()` or `html()` to read content from an input field, it doesn't do what you think. Use `val()`.

```
var data = escape($("#textfield").text());
```

Don't ever use `escape()`. It is a weirdo JavaScript-specific function that looks like URL-encoding but isn't. If you use it for URL-encoding you will corrupt plus signs and all non-ASCII characters.

The correct JavaScript function for URL-encoding is `encodeURIComponent()`. However, since you are using jQuery, much better to let it work out URL-encoding for you by passing an object in:

```
data: {xml: $("#textfield").text()},
```

Finally:

```
$data = urldecode($_POST["xml"]);
```

You don't have to (and shouldn't) URL-decode anything manually. PHP URL-decodes parameters in a request body into raw strings for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a practical maximum of 2,083 characters in the url; there is no limit for a POST request. A GET request will pass the parameters in the url whereas a post does not. It all depends on how much you're actually sending to determine which you should use or if you're sending sensitive data (use POST).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the data option on ajax calls means jquery will add these to the query string in a GET request.  Most browsers have a limit on the length of a get request.  If your xml data is too big, you should switch to POST.

Comment: The limit on GET imposed by browsers used to be about 4K generally, maybe it still is. I stopped using GET for anything heavyweight when I discovered that.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your php.ini

- post_max_size you may have to set
  your memory_limit to higher value..
- depends on the memory usage of your
  script also
- max_execution_time could    be a
  problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#btn_save").click(function() {
    var data = $("#textfield").text();
    $.ajax({
        url:        "validate.php",
        type:       "POST",
        data:       {"xml": data},
        complete:   function(e) { alert(e.responseText); }
    });
});
```